# If an underlying record changes before a batchable gets to the record is it still run/uses the latest values?

Tags: apex, batch

two examples

1. I am running the query `[SELECT Id From Account]` to select all accounts. The batchable gets to the account `(Name='Steve')` and in the mean time the underlying record has changed to `(Name='Bob')` would it return bob or steve?
2. I am running a query `[SELECT Id From Account WHERE Status = 'Cool']` same deal as the one above if by the time the record is seen it is now marked 'Uncool' or it was marked 'Uncool' and is now 'Cool' would it pop up?

Answer (score 3):

Queries always return the state of the database from the instant the query starts. So, the execute method will see the old record values, and records won't be added into, or removed from, the records that are processed, even if they now meet the criteria or no longer meet the criteria. The scope can definitely go "stale", and you should consider querying the records again in the execute method if you need to guard against this.

Comment: It would be sensible to indicate that the batch infrastructure captures the set of record IDs at the time `start` is called, matching the required criteria, but that it then queries collections of records before calling `execute` and these may have changed. I think [this article](https://foobarforce.wordpress.com/2015/10/25/batch-apex-query-behaviour/) includes a really interesting observation at the end; batches appear to query records prior to the invocation of the `execute` method, but in chunks larger than the batch's chunk size. I've not checked in the recent past to see what's what.

Comment: @PhilW right so the data could still be stale for example if your batch limit was 10 it might be querying in the background in batches of 200 or whetever. Atleast this explains the oddness we have been experiencing.

Comment: If that latter observation at the end of the article is still valid today, there seems likely a small window of time where stale data could arrive at the batch `execute` method, yes.